# Reference to System.Windows.Forms disappears?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reference, messagebox, infopath

I added a reference to System.Windows.Forms along with using System.Windows.Forms and every time I save and reopen my vsta project file, the reference and the using line disappears?

I added in the reference in order to use the MessageBox.Show() method?

I'm adding custom code for an InfoPath 2010 form using Visual Studio 2012 through the .NET Framework 4.

I'm not sure why I keep losing the reference?

Comment: Do you have the Productivity Power Tools installed? There's an option in there that Removes and Sorts Usings on save, so if you haven't actually added any code that references `System.Windows.Forms` that would explain why the using statement disappears.

Comment: Well I added it in for MessageBox.Show() otherwise I don't use it. Is there any other way for me to explicitly say that I'm using it?

Comment: That should be enough.

Comment: Then I have no idea why the line code and the reference both disappear